# Close connection in php using database class

Tags: php, mysqli

I have created a database class in PHP, and I only want the OOP style not the procedural style. Here is code when i try to close this me error. This function causing problem.

```
class MySQLDatabase
{
    private $connection;
    public $message;

    /**
     * MySQLDatabase constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->open_connection();
    }

    //Object oriented style
    public function open_connection()
    {
        // the constant comes form config
        $this->connection = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
        /*
         * This is the "official" OO way to do it,
         */

        if ($this->connection->connect_error) {
            die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
        } else {
            $this->message = "Success... " . $this->connection->host_info;
        }
    }

    public function close_connection(){
        if (isset($this->connection)) {
            mysqli_close($this->connection);
            unset($this->connection);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why would you close a oo connection through procedural

Comment: Help me get the grasp on the principles of OOP. _mysqli_connect()_ is what again in PHP? I think it's called a function. You are building a class around procedural code, nothing more or less ..

Answer (score 1):

```
public function close_connection()
    {
        if(isset($this->connection))
        {
            $this->connection->close();
            unset($this->connection);
        }
    }
```

Comment: where is mark as correct option ? there is not showing ?

Answer (score -1):

You're creating the new connection in object oriented style so you need to call it's [close](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php) method on connection object.

So your code will look something like this,

```
public function close_connection()
{
    if(isset($this->connection))
    {
        $this->connection->close();
        unset($this->connection);
    }
}
```